# Node Express.js app works fine locally but shows "Cannot GET /" in Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express

I have an Express.js server defined in my Node app as follows:

```
const express = require('express')
const SignRequest = require('./SignRequest/lambda/index.js')
const VerifyResponse = require('./VerifyResponse/lambda/index.js')

const port = "3000";

const app = express();
app.set('port', port)
app.use(express.static('../../web/dist'))
app.post('/signrequest', SignRequest.handler)
app.post('/verifyresponse', VerifyResponse.handler)
 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

The application works fine if I run it locally within my IDE (VS Code) via `node api/src/server.js`.

When I build it to Docker as follows:

`docker build --no-cache -t sdk-tester .`

And then run it as follows:

`docker run -p 3000:3000 app-name`

The image/container get built properly and are running, without any errors.

But when I try to access it outside of Docker (i.e. on my local machine's browser via http://localhost:3000/), I get this error:

`Cannot GET /`

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16 AS development

ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

WORKDIR /code/demo

COPY package.json /code/demo/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /code/demo/package-lock.json
RUN npm install

COPY . /code/demo

RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/swbc-certificate.crt

CMD [ "node", "api/src/server.js" ]

EXPOSE 3000
```

I have verified that all my files (including `server.js` in the API and the web files referenced by `app.use()` are indeed successfully copied to the container:

API:

[image]

Web:

[image]

So then, why the error?  Does it have something to do with the path I specified in `app.use(express.static('../../web/dist'))`?  And if so, why does the path work locally but not in Docker?

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of your issue, but `RUN export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=...` doesn't work. Each RUN statement runs in a separate shell and when the RUN statement finishes, the environment variables are lost. Use the ENV statement instead.

Comment: What does your complete file tree look like? Is the `api` folder a sibling of `web`?

It is most likely the way you're defining the path to the static files to serve.

You can always use something like an environment variable to specify the path. This way, you have control of exactly where to put the web files that you want to serve inside your image. If you leave it blank you can default it to what you have right now.

Comment: @moonstar-x the file tree on my local machine is similar to that which is deployed to Docker except that the parent folder is named differently.  `api` is a sibling of `web` (both are siblings of `demo`) and my `server.js` is under `api/src`.  Should I be using absolute rather than relative paths?

Comment: @moonstar-x on my local machine the file hierarchy for where the express server is located is <parent-app> -> demo -> api -> src, and the web files are in <parent-app> -> demo -> web -> dist.  (Where <parent-app> is the name of the parent application/folder).  On docker, the structure is similar. except that the paret folder is simply named "code".  See the screenshots in my original question.  With this in mind, what should I be passing into `app.use(express.static(...))`?

Answer (score 0):

Well.....it looks like the problem was with how I was building/passing the path to my static files in `express.static()`.  Modifying my `server.js` as follows fixed the issue.

before:

```
app.use(express.static('../../web/dist'))
```

after:

```
const path = require('path')
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../web/dist')))
```